# How can I get the value of a label in a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I used a UICollectionView and I used the cells to place a label which I associate my value. When you plug the cell I want to take the text to the selected label and use it to do anything else. How can I do?

With this code, I can go back to the index exactly, but I can not take the contents of the cell and put it in a string.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *strColorCell = cell.lblCustomCell.text;
    NSLog(@"Indice della cella: %i %i %@", indexPath.item, indexPath.section * 2 + indexPath.row, strColorCell);
}
```

Comment: Why would need to get the value from the cell?  Surely that's in whatever data structure you used to populate the cell in the first place (i.e. one of the `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assing tag value when you creating the `UILabel`

Then in your code you can get the label

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *custLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:labelTag];
    NSString *strColorCell = custLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"Indice della cella: %i %i %@", indexPath.item, indexPath.section * 2 + indexPath.row, strColorCell);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

This line

```
CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

does *not* give you the item that has been selected, it gives you an unused cell that has been recycled. You need to call

```
CustomCell *cell = [collectionView.dataSource collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to get the correct cell.

However, fundamentally, this is a wrong approach: you should use the `indexPath` to query the model for the text of the label, rather than asking the view. Take a look at the code of your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, and find the place where you use `indexPath` to set the text of the label. The text comes from your model classes. You should do the same thing in your `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: You should probably give him the way to access his array correctly while using the indexPath too.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus Since I don't see OP's code for the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, all I can do is to tell him where to look. It shouldn't be too hard, though.

Comment: Often the way to get data in didselect and cellforitem/row are similar. And since he doesn't do it right here I suspect the same thing is happening in the cellforitem. People tend to make the same or similar mistakes over and over in my experience. So teaching them the right way is preferable to me